# Centos 7 - firewalld - passthrough traffic with firewall-cmd

Tags: centos, iptables, firewalld

How can I allow traffic from some hosts network A (behind `eth0` interface) through my centos 7 box to network B (some hosts behind `eth1`).

**network A**: `1.1.1.0/24`

**network B**: `2.2.2.0/24`

Firewall interfaces:

**eth1**: `1.1.1.1`

**eth2**: `2.2.2.1`

Src Host: `1.1.1.30`

Destinations: `2.2.2.45 port 80/tcp and 2.2.2.46 port 80/tcp`

Forwarding is on and with `iptables` disabled I can reach the web server from `1.1.1.30`.

How can I realize that with `firewall-cmd`?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure to disable IPTABLES service as Both the FirewallD and IPTABLES service cannot co-exist at the same time.

To disable IPTABLES, execute `# systemctl stop iptables`

Next make sure to enable and start FirewallD service;

`# systemctl start firewalld && systemctl enable firewalld`

Now you need to assign each of available interfaces (in this case eth0 & eth1) to a particular network zones which are available on firewalld, by default.

Let assume; eth0 belongs to internal-zone(**network-A**) and eth1 belongs to public-zone(**network-B**). To do that;

`# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-interface=eth0`

`# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-interface=eht1`

Now your firewall setup is complete. As to configure rules, for example, allow http traffic sourced from host resides in **network-A** you need to set rules inbound on internal-zone;

`# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-service=http`

in addition, you need to enable masquerade on public-zone as to translate IP addresses when they send to network-B

`# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade`

Finally, reload the FirewallD daemon to effect the changes

`# firewall-cmd --reload`

To list out rules on a zone, for example on internal-zone

`# firewall-cmd --zone=internal --list-all`